# Changing Bootstrap animation progress bar animation duration with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the duration of the CSS3 animation used on the Twitter Bootstrap animated progress bar.
My desired result is to decrease the duration of the animation using jQuery so that I have a faster animation.

I've got the following HTML and CSS and used the following jQuery.

HTML:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active" style="width:102px;">
    <div id="test" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.progress-bar {
    background-color: #bd4a61;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I'm using the following jQuery to change the values but this doesn't seem to have any effect. I'm using Chrome as my test browser but I seem to get the behavior in all browsers.

jQuery:

```
$("#test").css("-webkit-animation-duration", "1s");
```

If I fetch the value of animation-duration after executing the jQuery it reads as being "1s" as opposed to the default "2s" but the visual effect remains unchanged.

EDIT: Using jQuery to hide and show the element after setting the value seems to get the effect working for Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like at least Chrome does not detect the change in the css property `animation-duration`. However, by removing and then re-adding the `progress-bar` class the animation when changing the `animation-duration` works when the re-adding of the progress-bar class is done in a `setTimeout`.

```
$('#test').css('animation-duration', '0.1s').removeClass('progress-bar');
setTimeout(function() { 
    $('#test').addClass('progress-bar');
}, 1);
```

This looks seriously ugly and error prone, but it works.

**Another and in my opinion better way** would be to set all animation properties. This works without having to fiddle around with adding and removing of the `progress-bar` class:

```
var secondFraction = '0.2'
$('#test').css('animation', secondFraction + 's linear 0s normal none infinite progress-bar-stripes');
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. jQuery needn't be involved.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I'm using them as an easy way to create a "flow" effect, as a result I need to change them dynamically using jQuery otherwise I would just apply new styles through the style sheet.

Comment: The `transition` on `progress-bar` only seems to occur when the width changes. Is it the `transition-duration` you want to alter or the  `animation-duration`? Do you want to alter the speed of the transition as it is occurring or do you want to change it for the next time the transition occurs?

Comment: I'd like to change the `animation` duration. I'm happy with the `transition` which occurs when the width changes.

Comment: I put together the following jsfiddle. This seems to work fine in Safari, and it works in other browsers if the progress bar is hidden and shown again using jQuery after attempting to change the `animation-duration`. http://jsfiddle.net/c2GYK/

Comment: @James I forked your fiddle and made it work in Chrome and firefox (at least on linux). The timeout thingy is a bit of a hack, but at least it works. http://jsfiddle.net/L2wjq/1/

Comment: @EmilH That's great! Thanks for your help. If you want to update or post a new answer I'll accept it. Do you happen to know if this is a quirk of Chrome and some other browsers?

Comment: @James Updated the answer, also found an in my opinion better way to do it :)

Comment: @EmilH The second option doesn't work for me unfortunately. Though I agree it would be preferred. I end up with the same behaviour as described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.progress-bar').css("width",
                function() {
                    return $(this).attr("aria-valuenow") + "%";
                }
        ) 
    });
    var counterBack = setInterval(function(){   
      
      var date = $("#time i").html(); 
      var d = date/30*100;
      var i = Math.round(d); 
       if (i < 20){
           $("#progress").addClass('progress-bar-danger').removeClass('progress-bar-info');
        }
        if (i < 70){
           $("#progress").addClass('progress-bar-info').removeClass('progress-bar-success');
        }
        if (i > 0){
          $('.progress-bar').css('width', i+'%');
        } else {
          $('.progress-bar').css('width', 0+'%');
          clearInterval(counterBack);
        }  
      }, 1000);
```

```css
.progress {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 25px;

}
.progress .skill {
  font: normal 12px "Open Sans Web";
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.progress .skill .val {
  float: right;
  font-style: normal;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.progress-bar {
  text-align: left;
  transition-duration: 3s;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
  
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css">
  <div class="progress">
  <div id="progress" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated active progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%;">
    <span class="sr-only"></span>
    <span id="time" class="skill">Your Time<i class="val">{{counter | async}}</i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```